# sqlite3: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, binding

Here is my code:

```
def update(id, title, author, year, isbn):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=? WHERE id=?", (title, author, year, isbn, id))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close
```

Getting the following error:

`Incorrect number of bindings supplied.  The current statement uses 4, and there are 5 supplied.`

The Udemy tutorial I'm following uses this exact code.  Is there something wrong with the SQL query here?

Comment: you have 4 ? and 5 parameters, hint missing isbn

Comment: wow i can't believe i missed this.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=? WHERE id=?", (title, author, year, id))